# Please svgify The Snowflakes!

Tags: bug, status-declined, winter-bash-2017

That's an absolute disaster.

I mean, see yourself at https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com - these snowflakes are from 2007 at most, but not from the coming 2018. They look poor compared to the glamorous Winter Bash logo.

[image]

Comment: So sad I've grown significantly since my original question on the similar topic... Nostalgia... https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245334/please-svgify-the-snowflake

Comment: Hmmm... I suppose in the glamorous Kingdom of Arendelle snowflakes are always in-focus as if created by a skilled team of animators. Unfortunately we can't afford that luxury for Winter Bash and must settle for [slightly out of focus flakes](https://www.mnn.com/earth-matters/climate-weather/blogs/how-snowflakes-are-formed).

Comment: They're the ghosts of snowflakes past.

Comment: They're blurred by my tears of joy at the thought of more hats.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Please svgify The Snowflake](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245334/please-svgify-the-snowflake)

Comment: @DaveNewton: Uh, no, it's a completely different UI element, given that that's [status-completed] and about the topbar.

Comment: If this is going to be marked as [tag:status-declined], shouldn't there be an answer explaining the decision?